# Is there a way to add options for paypal so users can select payment method before popup window?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is there way to add options so user can select payment method (by paypal or credit card).

I searched for an example but I didn't find anything suitable.

As an alternative, is there an option to select the purchase method,  before the popup window opens?

Comment: What are you asking?  Once put into the cart, user can view cart.  While on paypal's site viewing the cart, the use can checkout and in that process they can select whether to pay by paypal or by credit card.  Do you want them to select before going to paypal?  Or can you not figure out how they select once on paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once viewing the cart in paypal, the user can select how to pay.

If they have a paypal account and sign in, then to the right of "payment" is "change."  Click that "change" link and it brings up windows where you can pay by charge card or bank account instead of with paypal money.

If they don't have a paypal account or don't sign in, they can use the link on the bottom of the right side that says "pay with debit or credit card."

I've tested and tried both ways (for our group's website).  Hope that helps!